# Know database length/size in android

Tags: android, database

I searched android documentation,  but nothing found....

Is there any method to know the numer of elements which has a column?
If there isnt, how could i get it?

Comment: you mean count the not null elements of a column?

Comment: No, all the elememts... From first to last, including null values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDb,DATABASE_YOUR_TABLE);
```

[queryNumEntries](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29)